# Appium Is_displayed always returning true even though page has changed

Tags: python, ios-simulator, xcode7, appium, python-appium

```
Appium 1.5.0 
Xcode  7.3
IOS 10.11.4 OSX EI Capitan
Using on:Simulator iOS 8.1
```

On ios `is_displayed` is always returning `true` even though the page has changed.Is there a bug in appium?

```
Relevant Logs
```

```html
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (25 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.click() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element/16/click 200 1223 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element 
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","MARKETS","7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'findElement'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 60000 ms for condition
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementByAccessibilityId('MARKETS')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:29 +0000 Debug: Got new command 45 from instruments: au.getElementByAccessibilityId('MARKETS')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:29 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElementByAccessibilityId('MARKETS')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:29 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:29 +0000 Debug: Lookup returned [object UIANavigationBar] with the name "MARKETS" (id: 17).
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:29 +0000 Debug: responding with:
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:29 +0000 Debug: Running system command #46: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js /var/folders/4x/vy1bbyh92l9czkyswl5wypt80000gn/T/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"17"}}...
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (39 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"17"}}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"17"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element 200 1211 ms - 88 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element 
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//UIATableView[2]/UIATableCell[1]","7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'findElement'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 60000 ms for condition
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:30 +0000 Debug: Got new command 46 from instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:30 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:32 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:32 +0000 Debug: responding with:true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":"icon-menu-logo.png","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/0","x":10,"y":28,"width":40,"height":40},">":[]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"Vivek Singh","label":"Vivek Singh","value":"Vivek Singh","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/1","x":62,"y":31,"width":209,"height":26},">":[]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"vivek.singh@tradingtechnologies.com","label":"vivek.singh@tradingtechnologies.com","value":"vivek.singh@tradingtechnologies.com","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/2","x":62,"y":48,"width":209,"height":21},">":[]}},{"UIATableView":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":"rows 1 to 11 of 11","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3","x":0,"y":104,"width":320,"height":438},">":[{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"MARKETS","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/0","x":0,"y":104,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"MARKETS","label":"MARKETS","value":"MARKETS","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/0/0","x":65,"y":109,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"ORDER BOOK","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/1","x":0,"y":139,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"ORDER BOOK","label":"ORDER BOOK","value":"ORDER BOOK","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/1/0","x":65,"y":144,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"FILLS","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/2","x":0,"y":174,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"FILLS","label":"FILLS","value":"FILLS","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/2/0","x":65,"y":179,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"POSITIONS","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/3","x":0,"y":209,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"POSITIONS","label":"POSITIONS","value":"POSITIONS","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/3/0","x":65,"y":214,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"AUDIT TRAIL","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/4","x":0,"y":244,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"AUDIT TRAIL","label":"AUDIT TRAIL","value":"AUDIT TRAIL","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/4/0","x":65,"y":249,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":" ","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/5","x":0,"y":279,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":" ","label":" ","value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/5/0","x":0,"y":279,"width":320,"height":35},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"Settings","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/6","x":0,"y":314,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"Settings","label":"Settings","value":"Settings","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/6/0","x":20,"y":319,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"Feedback","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/7","x":0,"y":349,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"Feedback","label":"Feedback","value":"Feedback","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/7/0","x":20,"y":354,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"Help","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/8","x":0,"y":384,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"Help","label":"Help","value":"Help","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/8/0","x":20,"y":389,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":" ","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/9","x":0,"y":419,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":" ","label":" ","value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/9/0","x":0,"y":419,"width":320,"height":35},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"Sign out","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/10","x":0,"y":454,"width":320,"height":35},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"Sign out","label":"Sign out","value":"Sign out","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/10/0","x":20,"y":459,"width":141,"height":25},">":[]}}]}}]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"Stage-Cert","label":"Stage-Cert","value":"Stage-Cert","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/4","x":20,"y":540,"width":177,"height":21},">":[]}},{"UIANavigationBar":{"@":{"name":"MARKETS","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/5","x":0,"y":20,"width":320,"height":44},">":[{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/5/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":64},">":[{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/5/0/0","x":0,"y":64,"width":320,"height":0.5},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"icon nav menu","label":"icon nav menu","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/5/1","x":5,"y":26,"width":44,"height":30},">":[]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"Back","label":"Back","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/5/2","x":8,"y":31.5,"width":21,"height":21},">":[]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"MARKETS","label":"MARKETS","value":"MARKETS","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/5/3","x":119,"y":28,"width":82.5,"height":27},">":[]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"icon nav add","label":"icon nav add","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/5/4","x":271,"y":26,"width":44,"height":30},">":[]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"STAGE-CERT","label":"STAGE-CERT","value":"STAGE-CERT","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/5/5","x":85,"y":57,"width":150,"height":10},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"RENAME INSTRUMENT","label":"RENAME INSTRUMENT","value":"RENAME INSTRUMENT","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/6","x":60,"y":76,"width":156,"height":21},">":[]}},{"UIATextField":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":"NAME","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/7","x":10,"y":105,"width":256,"height":36},">":[{"UIATextField":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":"NAME","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/7/0","x":10,"y":105,"width":256,"height":36},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"RESET","label":"RESET","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/8","x":10,"y":161,"width":121,"height":36},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] ":{"name":"RESET","label":"RESET","value":"RESET","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/8/0","x":47,"y":168,"width":47,"height":22},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"SAVE","label":"SAVE","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/9","x":146,"y":161,"width":120,"height":36},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"SAVE","label":"SAVE","value":"SAVE","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/9/0","x":186,"y":168,"width":39,"height":22},">":[]}}]}},{"UIATableView":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":"row 1 of 1","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/10","x":0,"y":67,"width":320,"height":497},">":[{"UIATableCell":{"@":{"name":"GE Jul16","label":null,"value":"","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/10/0","x":0,"y":67,"width":320,"height":65},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"GE Jul16","label":"GE Jul16","value":"GE Jul16","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/10/0/0","x":10,"y":73,"width":219,"height":17},">":[]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"+0.030","label":"+0.030","value":"+0.030","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/10/0/1","x":226,"y":71,"width":77,"height":21},">":[]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"99.275 / ----","label":"99.275 / ----","value":"99.275 / ----","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/10/0/2","x":10,"y":86,"width":204,"height":25},">":[]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"99.280","label":"99.280","value":"99.280","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/10/0/3","x":214,"y":85,"width":90,"height":25},">":[]}}]}}]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"TOUCH TO ADD AN INSTRUMENT","label":"TOUCH TO ADD AN INSTRUMENT","value":"TOUCH TO ADD AN INSTRUMENT","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/11","x":56,"y":240,"width":210,"height":21},">":[]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"icon nav add","label":"icon nav add","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/12","x":124,"y":254,"width":74,"height":58},">":[{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":"icon-nav-add.png","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/12/0","x":150,"y":272,"width":22,"height":22},">":[]}}]}}]}},{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[]}},{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/2","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[{"UIAStatusBar":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/2/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":20},">":[{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/2/0/0","x":6,"y":0,"width":38,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars","label":"3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/2/0/1","x":49,"y":0,"width":13,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"11:43 AM","label":"11:43 AM","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/2/0/2","x":135,"y":0,"width":50,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"100% battery power","label":"100% battery power","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/2/0/3","x":290,"y":0,"width":25,"height":20},">":[]}}]}}]}},{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/3","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[]}}]}}}
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:32 +0000 Debug: Running system command #47: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js /var/folders/4x/vy1bbyh92l9czkyswl5wypt80000gn/T/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":"TT Mobile α","label":"TT Mobile α","value":null,"dom":null,"...
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (8190 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (5085 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":"TT Mobile α","label":"TT Mobile α","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0","x":0,"y":20,"width":320,"height":548},">":[{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementByIndexPath('/0/0/10/0')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:33 +0000 Debug: Got new command 47 from instruments: au.getElementByIndexPath('/0/0/10/0')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:33 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElementByIndexPath('/0/0/10/0')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:33 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:33 +0000 Debug: Lookup returned [object UIATableCell] with the name "GE Jul16" (id: 18).
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:33 +0000 Debug: responding with:
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:33 +0000 Debug: Running system command #48: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js /var/folders/4x/vy1bbyh92l9czkyswl5wypt80000gn/T/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"18"}}...
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (39 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"18"}}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"18"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element 200 3903 ms - 88 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element/18/click 
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args: ["18","7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'click'
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: au.tapById('18')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:34 +0000 Debug: Got new command 48 from instruments: au.tapById('18')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:34 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.tapById('18')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:34 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().elements()[0].elements()[10].elements()[0].tap()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:35 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:35 +0000 Debug: responding with:
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:35 +0000 Debug: Running system command #49: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js /var/folders/4x/vy1bbyh92l9czkyswl5wypt80000gn/T/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (25 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.click() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element/18/click 200 1210 ms - 76 
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook.local TT Mobile[44235]: -[MarketsViewController viewWillDisappear:]:178, Markets view - Saving watchlist to file.
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook.local TT Mobile[44235]: -[TTViewController viewWillAppear:]:30, Displaying view for InstrumentDetailViewController.
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook.local TT Mobile[44235]: -[TTViewController viewWillAppear:]:30, Displaying view for OrdersTableViewController.
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook.local TT Mobile[44235]: -[AnalyticsChartViewController webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]:150, Chart received request https://trade-stage.trade.tt/cert/m/chart
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook.local TT Mobile[44235]: -[AnalyticsChartViewController webViewDidStartLoad:]:128, Chart webview did start load
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook assertiond[44209]: assertion failed: 15E65 12B411: assertiond + 13690 [F3233EFE-D6AB-32E3-BB3E-2CC6D0333C88]: 0x1
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook.local assertiond[44209]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7a54a6d0; com.tradingtechnologies.TTMobile; pid: 44235>: 0xe00002c9
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook assertiond[44209]: assertion failed: 15E65 12B411: assertiond + 13690 [F3233EFE-D6AB-32E3-BB3E-2CC6D0333C88]: 0x1
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 21 11:43:35 Macbook.local TT Mobile[44235]: -[TTURLProtocol startLoading]:71, serving response from cache
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element/17/displayed 
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.elementDisplayed() with args: ["17","7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'elementDisplayed'
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: au.getElement('17').isDisplayed()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:37 +0000 Debug: Got new command 49 from instruments: au.getElement('17').isDisplayed()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:37 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElement('17').isDisplayed()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:37 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:37 +0000 Debug: responding with:
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-21 06:13:37 +0000 Debug: Running system command #50: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js /var/folders/4x/vy1bbyh92l9czkyswl5wypt80000gn/T/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":true}...
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (27 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":true}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.elementDisplayed() result: true
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element/17/displayed 200 1159 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/7bce70c4-a096-4268-a25a-91bdb4d219de/element
```

As you can `Element 17` is being identified and later `Element 18` is being clicked.Now the page on simulator has changed but still `Element 17` `is_diplayed` is `true`.
Any ideas?